# Base class is abstract, and derived is also abstract?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have the base class:

```
class CDigit
{
private:
int m_iDigit;
public:
CDigit() 
{
    m_iDigit = 0;
}
CDigit( const int digit ) 
{
    m_iDigit = digit;
}
void setDigit( const int digit )
{
    m_iDigit = digit;
}
int getDigit() const
{
    return m_iDigit;
}
virtual void output(ostream &x) = 0;
virtual bool less( CDigit *pDigit ) = 0;
};
```

And the derived class

```
class CExpected : public CDigit
{
private:
int m_iExpFreq;
public:
CExpected() : CDigit()
{
    m_iExpFreq = 0;
}
CExpected( const int dig, const int freq) : CDigit(dig)
{
    m_iExpFreq = freq;
}
CExpected( const CExpected& ce)
{
    m_iExpFreq = ce.m_iExpFreq;
    this->setDigit( ce.getDigit() );
}
    void output(ostream &x)
{
    x<<this->getDigit()<<" "<<this->m_iObsFreq;
}
bool less( CObserved *pDigit )
{
    if( ( pDigit->getDigit() == this->getDigit() ) && (pDigit->getObserved() == this->getObserved() ) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
...
};
```

The problem is that the compiler tells me that CExpected is an abstract class and I cannot instantiate it. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I had them implemented but didn't add them on here

Comment: Yes, because you have not defined the pure virtual methods (`output` and `less`) in derived class.

Comment: I did but didn't add them by mistake :( sorry

Comment: On an unrelated note, it **never** makes sense to prefix your classes with `C` (or any related prefix). This “convention” arose out of a misunderstanding, nothing more (Microsoft used it when their compiler didn’t yet understand namespaces, to disambiguate with other classes; but even then it wasn’t meant to be used by everybody, lest the disambiguation be lost).

Comment: Furthermore, having code of the form `if (…) return true; else return false;` makes no sense either, and is bad style. Just replace it with `return …;`

Comment: My assignment need them to be named that way. Good to know tho.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't implemented `output` and `less`. Any class where pure virtual functions aren't defined can't be instantiated.

A good compiler should show you a better message:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:53: error: cannot declare variable ‘c’ to be of abstract type ‘CExpected’
test.cpp:32: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘CExpected’:
test.cpp:27: note:  virtual void CDigit::output(std::ostream&)
test.cpp:28: note:  virtual bool CDigit::less(CDigit*)
```

If you want to make them optional, don't use the `= 0` specifier which indicates a *pure* virtual method (and is the mark of an abstract class).

Comment: Pure virtual, not just virtual.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the signatures differ:

```
virtual bool less( CDigit *pDigit ) = 0;
virtual bool less( CObserved *pDigit )
```

(unless CObserved were typedefed to CDigit)

The problem is that the types differ, and it cannot match to call polymorphically if derived because you would expect a promotion -- which isn't valid. Your definition in `CExpected` needs to match, and be declared as:

```
virtual bool less( CDigit *pDigit ) { ... }
```